# How to create rss feed from my category joomla 3.2.3?

Tags: joomla, rss, joomla3.0

Does Joomla 3.2 have an RSS feed creator in core as 2.5 had? I would like to create an RSS feed with articles from one of my joomla's category.

Comment: As my experience, the most flexible way is using obRSS. I use that component to create feeds for almost other components: ZOO, K2, Joomla Articles,...

Answer (score 7):

1.) Go to Extensions->Module Manager in the admin screen

2.) Create a new Module, the type of module is "Syndication."

3.) The only really important bit do here is to assign it to the menu item that displays the category you want to build the feed from (can either be a blog view or a list view). Assign it only to that item (choose "only selected items" from the dropdown, click select none to clear all the checks, then check only the category page you want to build the feed from).

4.) Fill in anything else the way you want. The module must be published, but technically it doesn't even need to be visible to do its work, though you might want it visible in order to let people click on the link to the feed. ;{>}

Caveat: It will create a feed in either RSS or Atom format. You want both, create two syndication modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the display format at the end of the category url in this way:

```
www.mypage.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=<YOUR_CATEGORY_ID>&format=feed&type=rss
```

When you add `&format=feed&type=rss` string at the end of the URL you transform the classic page in an RSS feed. You can change `type=rss` with `type=atom` if you want.

Answer (score -3):

1- Login to Joomla Admin
2-Go to Components>>Newsfeeds>Categories
--Create new category
3-Go to Compnents>>Newsfeeds>>Feeds
--Create a new Feed
4- Create a menu item linking to that RSS Feed. That is how easy it is! Hope that helps!

Comment: That's only the answer if you're listing feeds that are actually sourced at some other site. I thought the question was about creating a feed out of a category of articles on your own site.